# Laravel: Testing routes with custom request headers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

So the question is simple:

### How to send custom request header, when I testing with Laravel?

I'm trying to make like so:

```
$this->call('POST', '/my/route', ['params' => 'array'], [], ['X-Custom' => 'header']);
```

But when I call `Request::header('X-Custom')` in my controller, I didn't get it.
Yes, it's available in `Request::server('X-Custom')`, but it's not what I need.

So I need to get it in `Request::header()`.

PS: `Laravel 4`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to properly form the header, or it will be ignored. Try this:

```
this->call('POST', '/my/route', ['params' => 'array'], [], ['HTTP_X-Custom' => 'header']);
```

The `HTTP_` will be stripped when you look at your Request

Comment: Thx, it works! I think this is becose of symfony denepdence. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; Prefix your custom headers with 'HTTP_'

If anybody is interested in why this worked, read this issue:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1655

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel >= 5.1, the call method based on its definition:

```
call($method, $uri, $parameters = [], $cookies = [], $files = [], $server = [], $content = null)
```

needs an extra array before headers array:

```
this->call('POST', '/my/route', ['params' => 'array'], [], [], ['HTTP_X-Custom' => 'header']);
```